# daCapricorn / ArcMenu Binditem on click of anywhere on screen

Tags: android

i am using daCapricorn / ArcMenu library , in that library child get bind only on click of the icon .But i want to bind item if it does not clicked on icon , anywhere click should bind child to hidden position.

Thank you in advance.